# How do I use Watir::Waiter::wait_until to force Firefox to wait?

Tags: ruby, watir, firewatir, automated-tests

I have some buttons that get disabled when adding a user.
What I need to be able to do is have firewatir `wait_until` something is present.
I am trying to use this right now:

```
count = 10
while count > 0
browser.button(:name, "_eventId_addEmployee").click
Watir::Wait.wait_until_present {text.exist? newHireUsername}
end
count -= 1
end
```

For some reason I can't get the `wait_until` method to work correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do something like this,

browser.element_type(:id, "xxx").wait_until_present

Comment: How would you go about waiting until text is present?

Comment: Is the text wrapped in a div, span or paragraph tag?

Comment: The text is in a DataTable, within a div.

Comment: Can you post some sample HTML?

Comment: To wait until some text is present: `browser.wait_until { browser.element(:id => 'xx').text.include? 'this_text'}`

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using the `wait_until_present` option I used an until loop to wait for text to appear.
This by-passed attempting to use it so it does not qualify as an answer for my original question but want it here for others.

Comment: The wait_until_present feature is to remove the need for hacks like this. The newHireUserName is probably stuffed in a div, span, read-only text_field, or paragraph field <p>. Alastair's solution would work for nearly all those if you modify as: browser.element_type(:value => newHireUserName)